# Vertex 4th-degree connection in graph -Java Hashmap

Tags: java, graph, hashmap, connection

my Java code was to do the following things:
(1) build a graph (map) of friends connected to each other.
(2) check if any two people are connected  within 4th degree connection (fewer than 3 edges), e.g., A-> B(A &B 1st degree connection), A->B->C (A&C, 2nd degree connection), A->B->C->D (A&D, 3rd degree connection), A->B->C-D->E (A&E, 4th degree connection).

Now my Java code uses Hashmap to build a friend connecting map. Then search the Hashmap if two people (e.g., X and Y) are connected within 4 the degree connection. 
It works very well for a map of a small number of people. When it comes to a friend map of 3.3 million people, it works very well for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd connection. The 3rd connection search took about 20 minutes tested on my PC. But for the 4th degree connection, it could not finish after 50 hours.

Questions: I wonder if Hashmap is not the correct way when it comes to a big size of graph (map) like 3 million people. If not, what is the possible data structure to do it?

#

Build the friend connecting map:
    public HashMap> buildFriendMap(String inputFile){
        String paymentRecord = inputFile;

```
    try{
        FileInputStream prStream = new FileInputStream(paymentRecord);
        Scanner prScanner = new Scanner(prStream);
        while(prScanner.hasNextLine()){

            String line = prScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] columns = line.split(",");
               if(columns.length<3){
                  continue;
               }
            String sender = columns[1];
            String receiver = columns[2];

            if(!(sender.equals(" id1")) && !(receiver.equals(" id2"))){
                if(friendMap.containsKey(sender)==false){
                    friendMap.put(sender,new HashSet<String>());
                }
                friendMap.get(sender).add(receiver);

                if(friendMap.containsKey(receiver) ==false){
                    friendMap.put(receiver,new HashSet<String>());
                }
                friendMap.get(receiver).add(sender);

            }
        }
        prScanner.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return friendMap;
```

Check if two people are within the 4th degree connection:
    public String is4thDegreeFriend (String id1, String id2) {

```
    String sender = id1;
    String receiver = id2;
    String fraudFlag = "Unverified";

    if(!(sender.equals(" id1")) && !(receiver.equals(" id2"))){
        if(friendMap.containsKey(sender)==true){
            if(friendMap.get(sender).contains(receiver)==true){
                fraudFlag = "Trusted";
            }else if(friendMap.get(sender).contains(receiver)==false){
                Iterator index2nd = friendMap.get(sender).iterator();
                while (index2nd.hasNext()){
                    Object idx2nd = index2nd.next();
                    if(friendMap.get(idx2nd).contains(receiver)==true){
                        fraudFlag = "Trusted";
                    }else if(friendMap.get(idx2nd).contains(receiver)==false){
                        Iterator index3rd = friendMap.get(idx2nd).iterator();
                        while (index3rd.hasNext()){
                            Object idx3rd = index3rd.next();
                            if(friendMap.get(idx3rd).contains(receiver)==true){
                                fraudFlag = "Trusted";
                            }else if(friendMap.get(idx3rd).contains(receiver)==false){
                                Iterator index4th = friendMap.get(idx3rd).iterator();
                                while (index4th.hasNext()){
                                    Object idx4th = index4th.next();
                                    if(friendMap.get(idx4th).contains(receiver)==true){
                                        fraudFlag = "Trusted";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fraudFlag;
}
```

#

Thanks,

Comment: All of those `else if` statements should just be `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Dijkstra's Algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

You can treat each friend connection as a graph edge with a weight of 1.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say that there are 77359 vortex (unique people) in the connected network.